# How can I use wildcards in an Nginx map directive?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use Nginx to served cached files produced by a web application, and have spotted a potential problem; that the url-space is wide, and will exceed the Ext3 limit of 32000 subdirectories.

I would like to break up the subdirectories, making, say, a two-level filesystem cache. So, where I am currently caching a file at

```
/var/cache/www/arbitrary_directory_name/index.html
```

I would store that instead at something like

```
/var/cache/www/a/r/arbitrary_directory_name/index.html
```

My trouble is that I can't get `try_files`, or even `rewrite` to make that mapping. My searching on the subject leads me to believe that I need to do something like this (heavily abbreviated):

```
http {
    map $request_uri $prefix {
        /aa*   a/a;
        /ab*   a/b;
        /ac*   a/c;
        ...
        /zz*   z/z;
    }

    location / {
        try_files /var/cache/www/$prefix/$request_uri/index.html @fallback;

        # or
        # if (-f /var/cache/www/$prefix/$request_uri/index.html) {
        #     rewrite ^(.*)$ /var/cache/www/$prefix/$1/index.html;
        # }
    }
}
```

But I can't get the `/aa*` pattern to match the incoming uri. Without the `*`, it will match an exact uri, but I can't get it to match just the first two characters.

The Nginx documentation suggests that wildcards should be allowed, but I can't see a way to get them to work. Is there a way to do this? Am I missing something simple? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that globs are only supported with the special [hostname mode](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule#map). You need to use regular expressions to achieve this, so your map should look like this:

```
map $request_uri $prefix {
    ~^/aa(?<suffix>.*)$ /a/a/$suffix;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more careful reading of the Nginx documentation reveals that the functionality that I want is part of the Rewrite module. What I thought needed to be:

```
map $request_uri $prefix {
    /aa* a/a;
    /ab* a/b;
    /ac* a/c;
    ...
    /zz* z/z;
}
```

is easily implemented with this:

```
if ($request_uri ~= "/(\w)(\w)(.*)") {
    set $prefix $1/$2;
}
```

And then the try_files directive works like this:

```
location / {
    root /var/www/cache;
    try_files /$prefix$request_uri @fallback;
}
```